# What keys should I use for HashMap?

Tags: java, hash, hashtable

What key is the best for HashMap?

1. I used just decimal, each key is previous++, but it's just my idea i don't know if it efficient.
2. I read about hashCode, this value commonly used for hash tables, but people say to not misuse hashCode() as a key.

Waiting for your answers and links to resources.
Here's code snippet:

```
Identifier identifier = new Identifier();
identifier.setName(getString(currentToken));
identifier.setLine(currentLineNumber);
int key = identifier.hashCode();
tableOfIdentifiers.put(key, identifier);
```

Comment: Why don't you use the identifier directly? What's the reason for introducing a hash map?

Comment: Why are you using the hash code as the key in the map? Note that hash codes in general are not unique, so this might cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely rare for user's code to call `hashCode` directly outside of implementations of `hashCode` methods for custom objects. In particular, in your case the call is unnecessary, because `HashMap` and `HashSet` rely upon calling `hashCode` internally.

From your example it does not appear that you need `HashMap`: a `HashSet` should be sufficient.

```
private Set<Identifier> tableOfIdentifiers = new HashSet<Identifier>();
...
if (!tableOfIdentifiers.add(identifier)) {
    ... // Duplicate identifier is detected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, maps are used to have some key values pairs. The keys should be unique and understandable. Maps might have duplicate values for different keys, but if use hashcode as the key the map will overwrite your previous value. Try using logical names as keys. could be empcode, studentRollNumber etc.